# Breaking up a pivot style table in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table where values are held at a row level, so my data looks like this:

[image: Sample Table]

As you can see there is a C_KEY which then has a C_Value, what i want to be able to do is split of the C_Key values i need, so they become a Column header. 
Is this a possible action in SQL?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have come up with though I did not understand your question completely

```
select C_PEWF_UUID, C_PE_UUID , 
(case when C_KEY = 'languagingStatus' then C_Value end)as languagingStatus,
(case when C_KEY = 'taskColour' then C_Value end)as taskColour,
(case when C_KEY = 'progressPercent' then C_Value end)as progressPercent,
(case when C_KEY = 'turnaroundType' then C_Value end)as turnaroundType
from table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, 

I think i badly asked the Question, but i also think i have resolved it with a LEFT JOIN on my subquerey. 

SELECT  C_PE_UUID, C_VALUE AS COLOUR
                  FROM T_PE_WF_ATTRIBUTES
                  WHERE C_KEY = 'taskColour'
                  AND C_VALUE = 'red'

This means for my main query, i can restrict C_KEY to just the LanguageStatus results, then in the subquery i can return the taskColour results of just red, leaving the rest as null. 

So now my column headings will be 

C_PE_UUID, C_VALUE, COLOUR

But thanks for getting back to me. 
Ben

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C_KEY, C_VALUE FROM T_WORKFLOW WF

LEFT JOIN (SELECT C_PE_UUID, C_VALUE AS COLOUR FROM T_WORKFLOW
           WHERE C_KEY = 'taskColour' AND C_VALUE = 'red') CL
    ON WF.C_PE_UUID=CL.C_PE_UUID
```

This was my solution to breaking out the range of C_KEY values to have their own heading in the dataset.